# Populate UITableView with Dictionary data (Swift)

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, nsdictionary

I'm making an social networking app with a NodeJS backend. The app gets its data from the MongoDB associated with the Node app with a `GET` request. I have figured out how to parse the JSON returned from the `GET` request as a native Dictionary, but can not find a clean way of turning each of the objects in the dictionary into a `TableViewCell` in my `TableView`. The Dictionary is basically this:

```
["username":"personWhoPosted", "taggedUsername":"personWhoIsTagged", "imageURL":"http://urlofimageposted.com"]
```

I need each of those to fill different values/labels inside the `TableViewCell`s

Comment: can you just iterate over the dictionary and set each value of the (key,value) pair to the label in your table view cell ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to utilize `indexPath`, I would keep a copy of array of dictionary keys.

```
func fetchData() {
  // ....
  // Your own method to get the dictionary from json
  let self.userDict = ["username":"personWhoPosted", "taggedUsername":"personWhoIsTagged", "imageURL":"http://urlofimageposted.com"]

  // Keep a copy of dictionary key
  let self.userDictKeyCopy = Array(self.userDict.keys)
  // You may want to sort it
  self.userDictKeyCopy.sort({$0 < $1})
}

// Table view delegates

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  return self.userDictKeyCopy.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(kCustomCell) as! CustomTableCell

  // Assuming one section only
  let title = self.userDictKeyCopy[indexPath.row] // e.g. "taggedUsername"

  cell.titleLabel = title
  cell.contentLabel = self.userDict[title] // e.g. "personWhoIsTagged"

  return cell
}
```

Comment: What if the the JSON is like [{"username":"personWhoPosted", "taggedUsername":"personWhoIsTagged", "imageURL":"http://urlofimageposted.com"}, {"username":"personWhoPosted", "taggedUsername":"personWhoIsTagged", "imageURL":"http://urlofimageposted.com"}] and there are multiple sets of objects inside? The inner ones contain the data for each post.

Comment: You need to decide what do you want to do. For example, you could have multiple table view sections, where each section is corresponding to one post. For things like this, it's better to direct map three dictionary fields, to a constant row of index path. E.g. `if indexPath.row == 0 {cell. contentLabel = userDict['username']} else if indexPath.row == 1 {...}`. Or you could have a custom cell, which will display all three fields, so that no multiple sections involved.

Answer (score 0):

```
let yourDict = ["username":"personWhoPosted", "taggedUsername":"personWhoIsTagged", "imageURL":"http://urlofimageposted.com"]
```

**Number of rows in section**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return yourDict.count
}
```

**Cell for row at**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    let key = Array(yourDict)[indexPath.row].key
    let value = yourDict[key]
    return cell
}
```